# API Яндекс Расписаний передает странные рейсы

Tags: яндекс-расписания

подскажите, пожалуйста. Тестирую расписание АПИ Яндекс расписания и столкнулся с проблемой: на мой запрос по одному вокзалу мне приходит ответ с дублирующимися рейсами, иногда рейсы точь в точь похожи но отличаются только на минуту. Хотя запрос делаем, как указано в документации.

Так же у меня есть вопрос, правильно ли я понимаю, что я получаю от Яндекса ответ и могу сравнивать его с расписанием на сайте Яндекс расписание? Просто проблема в том, что расписание, которое приходит по АПИ не похоже на расписание на сайте Яндекс Расписание, поскольку там во первых есть дубли рейсов, во вторых рейсы-дубли отличающиеся только минутой и в целом новые рейсы, которых на сайте я не наблюдаю. Правильно ли я понял, что ответ от Яндекса по АПИ должен совпадать с расписанием на сайте?

Вот пример ответа, который дает Яндекс Апи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сегодня на РБК была статья, что у Яндекса как минимум по аэропорту Домодедово какие-то проблемы и что-то они там с сервисом расписаний сейчас шаманят в целом.

Comment: Прикрепил скрин, что передает Яндекс АПИ 
Вижу, что передаются одинаковые рейсы, их отличие только в uid (это называется нитка - маршрут и время движения транспортного средства от начальной точки движения до конечной, привязанный к определенной дате). То есть он передает одинаковые маршруты, с отличием в том, что один маршрут актуален в 3 4 6 7 декабря а другой только 11 декабря. Ну как я понял. Почему так - не понимаю